# Installing packages to a Linux Server without internet connection

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I have a production server (in my case Suse Linux) that is not connected to the outside internet. I can copy files to it via SCP and I have root rights, but I would not be able to connect to remote repos.

I would like to install several packages on this production server. Is there a way to run an installation on a parallel server (connected to the internet), keep all downloaded installation source files, copy them to the prod server and run there the installation of the new packages with local packages?

Comment: or a proxy with rules to only allow access to the package servers ... depending on your local security policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program called yumdownloader to download the rpms in the parallel server connected to internet.

```
yum install yum-utils
yumdownloader <package_name>
```

And in the target server, you can scp the rpms and install it using the below command.

```
yum localinstall <rpm_name>
```

Comment: SuSE doesn't have `yum`